# Order flattened list without changing group order

Tags: linq, sorting

I have a collection where items are not ordered. Each item has 2 properties: one used to group them and other is to order them in that group. And I need to produce a collection, where items become ordered within groups, but group order doesn't change.

To example, this is input:

> (12, 0), (44, 0), (22, 1), (100, 0), (1, 0), (22, 3), (22, 2)

**How to get this (below) output?**

> (12, 0), (44, 0), (22, 1), (22, 2), (22, 3), (100, 0), (1, 0)

Notice items of group `22`: they are moved together to where group appears first and are ordered between themselves.

Here is repro (using C# 7.0 tuples, don't forget to target 4.7 framework in VS2017):

```
(int A, int B)[] input = new[] { (12, 0), (44, 0), (22, 1), (100, 0), (1, 0), (22, 3), (22, 2) };

var output = input.OrderBy(o => o.A).ThenBy(o => o.B).ToArray();
//var output = input.Select((o, i) => new { Index = i, Item = o }).GroupBy(o => o.Item.A)...SelectMany().ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", output.Select(o => $"({o.A}, {o.B})")));
```

Uncommented part also sorts groups, producing wrong output. And then I stumble (commented part) with indexes, grouping, flattening.. it can't be that hard or should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of the problem is also a description of the answer - group and then sort each group. The definition of `GroupBy` specifies that groups will appear in the output in the original order from the input:

```
var output = input.GroupBy(s => s.A).SelectMany(sg => sg.OrderBy(s => s.B)).ToArray();
```